# How to launch docker container from CLI in MacOS (eg `docker run ...`)?

Tags: command-line, bash, homebrew, zsh, docker

How can I launch a docker container from the command-line in MacOS?

In Debian Linux, I can execute the following commands to install docker, launch a new docker container based on the latest version of Debian, and get a shell inside that container

```
# securely install docker and let our user interact with it
sudo apt-get install docker.io
sudo bash -c 'gpasswd -a "${SUDO_USER}" docker'
su - `whoami`

# "securely" download and run latest Debian container
# * https://security.stackexchange.com/q/238529/213165
export DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST=1
docker run --rm -it --entrypoint /bin/bash debian:stable-slim
```

In MacOS, I can ([insecurely](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/394401/cryptographic-integrity-and-authentication-validation-of-homebrew-installer)) install docker as follows

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
brew install --cask docker
```

But then I get `command not found` errors when attempting to run a new container (in both zsh and bash)

```
user@host ~ % export DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST=1
user@host ~ % docker run --rm -it --entrypoint /bin/bash debian:stable-slim 
zsh: command not found: docker
user@host ~ % bash

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
bash-3.2$ export DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST=1
bash-3.2$ docker run --rm -it --entrypoint /bin/bash debian:stable-slim 
bash: docker: command not found
bash-3.2$
```

Note that this is a headless machine with no access to the GUI. The only access provided is via ssh (with sudo for root permission).

How can I launch and enter a new docker container from the command-line in MacOS?

Comment: And what does the cask install?  Where does it put the binaries?  Are these binaries on your $PATH?

Comment: @MarcWilson I searched the entire filesystem (with `find`) and I cannot find an executable named `docker` anywhere. Hence this question. I imagine there's some weird undocumented step that I'm missing. It's probably trivial with the GUI, but I have no idea how to proceed with only CLI.

Comment: But that's not what I asked you.  *What* does the cask install and *where* does it install it?

Comment: Do you have an Intel or an ARM Mac? According to [docker.rb](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/HEAD/Casks/docker.rb) you should get both a Docker.app in /Applications and /usr/local/bin/docker when installing the cask. Are these files/directories where they should be?

Comment: `cat /proc/cpuinfo` gives `cat: /proc/cpuinfo: No such file or directory`. But I'm pretty sure it's Intel.

Comment: I have a directory located at `/Applications/Docker.app`. I do not have a binary located at `/usr/local/bin/docker`. If I had to guess, there's some sort of GUI window that's popping-up that I cannot see. Maybe brew just installs a (GUI) installer? Or it doesn't put the binary in-place until after I accept a EULA? Anyway, I need a CLI-only solution.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments of the now-deleted question, I tried installing docker via `brew install docker` (instead of cask) and now I have this binary, when executed with `/usr/local/Cellar/docker/20.10.17/bin/docker run hello-world` it outputs `docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.`

Comment: Well, the cask should install to /usr/local/bin, strange. Anyway, can you run Docker.App?

Comment: I can run `open /Applications/Docker.app` as root. It exits 0 immediately with no output.

Comment: @MichaelAltfield looking at the man page for `open` I see there are two flags that may do what you need: `-g  Do not bring the application to the foreground.` and `-j  Launches the app hidden.` Do either of those two help?

Comment: @JoshuaSkrzypek if I execute `sudo open -g /Applications/Docker.app`, it still exits 0 immediately with no output. If I execute it with the `-j` argument intead, it exits 0 immediately with no output. If I execute it with both the `-g` and `-j` arguments, it exits 0 with no output.

Comment: @MichaelAltfield oh, hold on, my mistake. I did not read through all of your comments, sorry!! Digging around it seems that you may have to jump through a lot of hoops to get all of the privileged helpers in place that you'd need to run docker on mac without doing it via the docker desktop app (i.e. the cask). FWIW, take a look through this issue/comment https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2359#issuecomment-943131345. I see below that you found the doc about the headless installation, but proper CLI control is still on the roadmap: https://github.com/docker/roadmap/issues/172

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, Docker cannot be installed on a headless machine running MacOS.

I finally gave-up and had someone plug a damn monitor into the Mac Mini in the datacenter. When they did, they saw a window that said

> **"Docker" is an app downloaded from the internet. Are you sure you want to open it?**
>
> Homebrew Cask downloaded this file on 3 May 2022 from [www.docker.com](http://www.docker.com). Aplle checked it for malicious software and none was detected.

It's super annoying that *no* output was given by Apple on the CLI to indicate this, but whatever.

I figured, for future reference, I'd bypass this using the CLI. You can do so as follows:

```
xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine /Applications/Docker.app
```

I ran `sudo open /Applications/Docker.app` again. This time it exited 1 with an error message

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -600 for the file /Applications/Docker.app.
```

This is where I gave-up on the CLI. In the GUI was a window that said:

> **Docker desktop needs privileged access.**
>
> Docker Desktop needs privileged access to install its networking components and links to the Docker apps.
>
> You will be asked for your password.

I just clicked "OK" and typed my password into the GUI.

After I did that, the docker binary was available

```
user@host ~ % ls /usr/local/bin/docker
/usr/local/bin/docker
user@host ~ %

user@host ~ % export DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST=1

user@host ~ % docker run --rm -it --entrypoint /bin/bash debian:stable-slim 
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'.
user@host ~ %
```

The above error was resolved by ticking "I accept the terms" and clicking `Accept` in a silly ToS that also appears to be only available to the GUI :facepalm:

After that, I re-opened Docker again

```
open -a Docker
```

Again, it exited immediately and no bloody output was printed on the terminal. But in the GUI a window opened that said Docker was starting. After half a minute or so, I could finally start a damn container

```
user@host ~ % docker run --rm -it --entrypoint /bin/bash debian:stable-slim
Unable to find image 'debian:stable-slim' locally
docker.io/library/debian@sha256:3d412a8a2e0f087738e6185c5cddab08827880a23e5bd9dc8b2494d89e4b33fd: Pulling from library/debian
2bc8f4ca4fd1: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:3d412a8a2e0f087738e6185c5cddab08827880a23e5bd9dc8b2494d89e4b33fd
Status: Downloaded newer image for debian@sha256:3d412a8a2e0f087738e6185c5cddab08827880a23e5bd9dc8b2494d89e4b33fd
Tagging debian@sha256:3d412a8a2e0f087738e6185c5cddab08827880a23e5bd9dc8b2494d89e4b33fd as debian:stable-slim
root@4d255f94ce06:/#
```

## Update

I [discovered](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/6504#issuecomment-1264705017) that there's a [documentation page with the commands to install docker from the CLI](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/mac-install/#install-from-the-command-line)

```
xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine /Applications/Docker.app
/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/install --accept-license --user=`whoami`
sudo /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/Docker --unattended --install-privileged-components
open -a /Applications/Docker.app
```

But I haven't tested this.

Comment: I filed a bug report about this https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/6504

Comment: `sudo open whatever.app` will usually fail because the user running the application will differ from the user "owning" the screen, resulting in the -600 error you get. This is not related to Docker.

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't used this as extensively as I have Docker Desktop, you can install [Colima](https://github.com/abiosoft/colima) along with Docker community tools.

Both are available in [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) and—once that is installed—can be simply run like so:

```
brew install colima docker
colima start
```

Once the Colima VM has started, regular Docker CLI commands will just work. For example, to start an Alpine container and get a shell:

```
docker run -it alpine
```

Colima also supports the (currently) experimental [Rosetta on Linux](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/virtualization/running_intel_binaries_in_linux_vms_with_rosetta) support that makes it possible to use Rosetta technology to run Intel Docker images on Apple Silicon.

```
colima start --vz-rosetta
```

The default QEMU is also available, if you have difficulty with Rosetta.